# XML и пространства имен

Tags: xml

Здравствуйте! У меня такой вопрос: почему в XML пространства имен указываются как URL? 
Например так:

```
xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
```

Какой в этом смысл?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это всего лишь соглашение. Имя пространства имени должно быть уникальным, уникальность имени проще всего контролировать именно тогда, когда он заведен как URI/URL. Неявно предполагается, что доменные имена контролируются разработчиками пространств имен - соответственно минимизируются коллизии.

В некоторых случаях, действительно по этим ссылкам лежат схемы/DTD xml'ок.

Да, и еще - это [рекомендация комитета W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/xml-names/#sec-intro)